# browserify will not compile express js

Tags: node.js, npm, browserify

I wrote a very basic express.js app. Then tried to make it one .js file. Browserify compiled the whole thing to a one file. But browserify-compiled code didn't work. As far as I know, browserify just replaces require statements with module codes. Error is:

```
C:\Users\HP\n\express\app.js:27025
  __proto__: http.IncomingMessage.prototype
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at Object.__dirname.173.accepts (C:\Users\HP\n\express\app.js:27025:34)
    at s (C:\Users\HP\n\express\app.js:1:316)
    at C:\Users\HP\n\express\app.js:1:367
    at Object.__dirname.170../application (C:\Users\HP\n\express\app.js:26823:11)
    at s (C:\Users\HP\n\express\app.js:1:316)
    at C:\Users\HP\n\express\app.js:1:367
    at Object.__dirname.168../lib/express (C:\Users\HP\n\express\app.js:26154:18)
    at s (C:\Users\HP\n\express\app.js:1:316)
    at C:\Users\HP\n\express\app.js:1:367
    at Object.__dirname.153.express (C:\Users\HP\n\express\app.js:24010:15)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Browserify* is designed specifically to package code for a browser.

Node.js supports a number of modules that a browser doesn't which have to be emulated by [builtins](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/blob/e35437af10b9b628885102a6b8e0d1f39cb16c8d/lib/builtins.js). These modules will be replaced by a browser-specific shim. Some only supply a subset of the Node API that makes sense to have in a browser.

So you are running an app that has converted all the Node.js modules to support running what it can in a browser, back in Node where the modules are available but are no longer being used.

Try [rollup](http://rollupjs.org/) or you could possibly configure [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to work like you need

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As far as I know, browserify just merges these .js files by their require statements. I actually don't want to use it in browser. Just for gathering my all application into a file. I was going to run the bundled file by "node bundle.js". Can't browserify get http module's code into that little file? Because at the end of the chain, after the express.js and some stuff, http module comes. And browserify can merge that module's code too, right?

Comment: @UmutÖzdemir No, Browserify is designed specifically for a browser: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#compatibility  Maybe try [rollup](http://rollupjs.org) or you might be able to get [babel](https://babeljs.io) to work like you need.

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same issue but like you said the compile code should work on server side. I solved it from this link:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/bundling-nodemodules-your-nodejs-app-one-single-file-xuan-son-nguyen/

Use browserify for bundling and terser for minifying. Starting by installing them globally:

```
npm install -g browserify
npm install -g terser
```

Next, we have to add a build script to package.json

```
...
"scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "browserify --node --ignore-missing index.js | terser > bundle.js"
}
...
```

Each time you want to promote to production, you have to make a new bundle:

```
npm run build
```

A new file called "bundle.js" will be created.

Let there be peace, and there was peace. Happy coding.