# Node.js - Browsify - Cannot compile the bundled file using node compiler

Tags: node.js

I am developing a Node.js application using Express. When I do node Node.js, this is working perfectly on localhost:3000.

Now I used browsify to bundle this to a file called bundle.js, and tried node bundle.js, this is giving an error like:

> typeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

from the following line in bundle.js (detailed context of bundle.js is given below):

```
var req = Object.create(http.IncomingMessage.prototype)
```

Node.js file:

```
var sql = require("mssql");
var express = require('express');
var http = require("http");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
//Enabling CORS 
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, contentType,Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
});
app.get('/',function(req,res){
res.send('Working');
});
```

Bundle.js in more detail:

```
/**
* Module dependencies.
* @private
*/

var accepts = require('accepts');
var deprecate = require('depd')('express');
var isIP = require('net').isIP;
var typeis = require('type-is');
var http = require('http');
var fresh = require('fresh');
var parseRange = require('range-parser');
var parse = require('parseurl');
var proxyaddr = require('proxy-addr');

/**
* Request prototype.
* @public
*/

var req = Object.create(http.IncomingMessage.prototype) ---- Error here

/**
* Module exports.
* @public
*/

module.exports = req

/**
* Return request header.
*
* The `Referrer` header field is special-cased,
* both `Referrer` and `Referer` are interchangeable.
*
* Examples:
*
*     req.get('Content-Type');
*     // => "text/plain"
*
*     req.get('content-type');
*     // => "text/plain"
*
*     req.get('Something');
*     // => undefined
*
* Aliased as `req.header()`.
*
* @param {String} name
* @return {String}
* @public
*/

req.get =
req.header = function header(name) {
    if (!name) {
        throw new TypeError('name argument is required to req.get');
    }

    if (typeof name !== 'string') {
        throw new TypeError('name must be a string to req.get');
    }

    var lc = name.toLowerCase();

    switch (lc) {
        case 'referer':
        case 'referrer':
        return this.headers.referrer
            || this.headers.referer;
        default:
          return this.headers[lc];
    }
};
```

More interestingly, I debugged bundle.js and node.js files separately, and for node.js inside the http there is an IncomingMessage, but not for bundle.js, which I think is the issue, but don't know how to rectify and the reason.

Please see the screenshots below:

```
bundle.js:
```

[image: Bundle]

```
node.js:
```

[image: Node]

Comment: this might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42214614/browserify-will-not-compile-express-js

Comment: Hi, But can you please let me know how/where to use builtin?

Comment: Hi. did you solve the problem? I've the same problem, even if I don't user Express

Comment: Hi,were you able to solve this?